# Include JQuery countdown in Django

Tags: javascript, jquery, django

I'm new with Django and this question is probably very basic. I would like to implement this Jquery countdown (http://keith-wood.name/countdown.html) in my Django app. But I have no idea how to include some javascript in my django templates. 
Here is what I tried to include in my template:

```
<script type="text/javascript"  src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<style type="text/css">@import "/Users/marc-antoine.lacroix/Desktop/JQuery/jquery.countdown.package-1.6.0/jquery.countdown.css";</style>
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ STATIC_URL }}js/jquery.countdown-fr.js"></script>
<script language="javascript">
var newYear = new Date(); 
newYear = new Date(newYear.getFullYear() + 1, 1 - 1, 1); 
 $('#defaultCountdown').countdown({until: newYear}); 
</script>
```

But nothing appears in my page. What did I do wrong? Is it the good way to include JQuery in my template?

I know several questions has been asked about it, but I didn't find how to solve my problem.

Any help would be very welcome.

Now, I tried:

```
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<script type="text/javascript"    src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<style type="text/css">@import "/Users/marc-antoine.lacroix/Desktop/JQuery/jquery.countdown.package-1.6.0/jquery.countdown.css";</style>
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ STATIC_URL }}js/jquery.countdown-fr.js"></script>
<script language="javascript">

$(document).ready(function(){

var newYear = new Date(); 
newYear = new Date(newYear.getFullYear() + 1, 1 - 1, 1); 
$('#defaultCountdown').countdown({until: newYear}); 

});
</script>

</head>
<body>

<div id="defaultCountdown"> </div>

</body>
```

Still nothing!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you include `<div id="defaultCountdown"></div>` somewhere on your page?
Also it would be a good idea to put your javascript code inside ready event, like so:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    //your code here
});
```

Comment: Thanks. I tried but it doesn't work. I tried that:              <script language="javascript">

$(document).ready(function(){
<div id="defaultCountdown">
var newYear = new Date(); 
newYear = new Date(newYear.getFullYear() + 1, 1 - 1, 1); 
$('#defaultCountdown').countdown({until: newYear}); 
</div>
});
</script>

Comment: May be I have to add something in my views.py?

Comment: No, you dont put `<div id="defaultCountdown"></div>` (which is html element) inside `<script>`, put it somewhere in `<body>`, and in `<head>` put `<script type="text/javascript">$(document).ready(function(){
    var newYear = new Date(); 
newYear = new Date(newYear.getFullYear() + 1, 1 - 1, 1); 
 $('#defaultCountdown').countdown({until: newYear}); 
});</script>`

Comment: check nested function code, you write html and you should code javascript.

Comment: I tried to do that. I edited my question to show you what I have now. Still nothing appears.

Comment: Pasted your example to http://jsfiddle.net/usvGt/ and it works. Maybe the problem is somewhere else?

Comment: It does work, thank you very much! Now I have an object with a DateTime called "real_start". I would like the countdown to go to this DateTime for every objects I have. Do you have an idea of how to do that? I tried to replace "newYear" by {{object.real_start}}, and I put the <div id="defaultCountdown"></div> in a loop that displays my objects. But the countdown doesn't work anymore.

Comment: You can not use multiple elements with the same id. Either use classes or use a different id for each element.

Comment: Ok, thank you. I will create a new question for that because I'm a bit lost.